# Ensure method A is called after every call of B (an abstract implemented method)?

Tags: java

Having this tasteful class

```
     public abstract class CakeSkill 
     {

         //.. 

         boolean cherry=false;

         private void finalMandatoryTouch()
         {        
              cherry=true;
         }                
         abstract public void cook();
     }
```

A class that extends it would be something like

```
     class Cheff extends CakeSkill 
     {
         //..

         void cook()
         {
         //..Secret recipe
         }     
     }
```

But of course this won't work,

*finalMandaroryTouch()* hasn't been called, then **no cake will end with a cherry..**

**[EDIT]**

This one *could* be a solution

```
       class MemoriousCheff extends CakeSkill 
       {
           //..

           void cook()
           {
               //..Secret recipe
               finalMandatoryTouch();
           }     
       }
```

*but* requires :

- Cheff to have a perfect memory that don't forget to call finalMandatoryTouch()
- Making finalMandatoryTouch() to be *protected* (at least)

**[/EDIT]**

It would be great! (but no Java) if something like this could be done

```
  abstract public void cook()   
  {  
    @implementedMethod

    finalMandatoryTouch();        
  }
```

How can be implemented this useful functionality ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `cook` to a protected method `cookImpl` then have a public *final* method called cook:

```
public final void cook()
{
    cookImpl();
    finalMandatoryTouch();
}

protected abstract void cookImpl();
```

That way the subclass only needs to worry about `cookImpl`, but callers of `cook` get the cherry on top. Callers not in the same package or class hierarchy won't even see `cookImpl`, so won't be able to call it directly.

This is the [*template method pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), basically.

Answer (score 3):

It's called the **Template method** pattern.

```
final public void cook() {  
    mainCookRecipe();
    finalMandatoryTouch();        
}

abstract public void mainCookRecipe();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class CakeSkill {

    public void cook() {
        doCook();
        finalMandatoryTouch();
    }

    protected abstract doCook();

    private finalMandatoryTouch() { ... }
}
```

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `cook()` method to an actual method and then invoke a separate `abstract` method as well as your `finalMandatoryTouch()` method.

In your `abstract` class:

```
 public void cook() {
     specificCook();
     finalMandatoryTouch();
 }

 abstract void specificCook();
```

Comment: Oops - think you mean `abstract void specificCook();`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that inheritance is not the right way to model your problem. In Java you can only inherit from *one* class, and since it's also a very static relationship, it limits your chef in the skills he can perform.

A better way would be to use composition. Cooking skills could be [strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) that the chef performs:

```
interface CookingSkill {
  void cook();
}

class CakeSkill implements CookingSkill {
  private boolean cherry = false;
  private void finalMandatoryTouch() {
    cherry = true;
  }
  public void cook() {
    //...
    finalMandatoryTouch();
  }
}

class Chef {
  private CookingSkill cookingSkill;
  // getters and setters ...
  public void cook() {
    // ...
    cookingSkill.cook();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now you can assign different cooking skills to your chef.